# What does "compare at" mean in ads?

Tags: meaning

A product priced 60$ is advertised by "compare at 100$". What does that mean? Why should I compare it like that?

Comment: It's saying that the price is usually $100 or other competitors sell it for $100. That suggestion may or may not be misleading, but that's what it's implying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first-posted answer explains the function of *compare at* in adertising, but does not explain why that particular construction came to serve that purpose (which seems to be a part of what puzzled the OP). The reason is that 'compare at $100', as used in advertising, is a conventional abbreviation for something like:

> **Compare** this product, which we sell for $60, to the similar products that other sellers sell **at $100**, and you will see that they are essentially the same.

It is a part of this advertising strategy that the advertiser does not explicitly say that you will save $40 by buying the product from them, but leaves the appearance of encouraging you to make the comparison yourself and so reach that conclusion on your own.

Answer (score 4):

The **compare at** price is a price that the seller *suggests* this same item (or, as noted in comments, *a comparable item*) sells for elsewhere, or is the full retail price at some places.

It can be used to make the buyers believe that they are saving money, as there is no regulation in place to prevent inflating the *compare at* price to make the *for sale* price seem a better value.

See [this article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/tj-maxx-being-sued-for-those-beloved-compare-at-prices_us_55af9b48e4b07af29d56de81) about a suit against a retail chain for misleading **compare at** prices.

Comment: I agree with most of this answer, but I'd add that the suggestion might not be that the same item sells for the higher price elsewhere but that equivalent or similar products from other manufacturers sell for the higher price. (The more ambiguity the better.)